# How can I move the boot drive (ie the one with GRUB)?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7, drive

I have two drives and I installed Ubuntu 17.10 while my Windows 7 drive was mounted. Therefore GRUB was accidentally installed to drive with windows 7. I've been using it for months and it's working ok, but how can I move GRUB to the drive where Ubuntu is installed?

Answer (score 1):

I used a program called GRUB customizer and its **install to MBR** option, selecting `/dev/sdf` (the label of my Ubuntu hard disk).

That solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score -3):

Boot into Ubuntu. Open terminal and run

`sudo apt install grub-pc grub-pc-bin`

If this returns that GRUB is already installed, run

`sudo apt remove grub-pc grub-pc-bin`

**CAUTION:** Do not turn off your PC after unistalling GRUB as you will not be able to boot into any OS. 
Then install GRUB using given command.

Then follow on screen instructions and choose your hard disk  as a place to install **GRUB**

Voila GRUB is now installed on your hard drive.